# Let $x>0$ , $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. Then find limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

> For $x>0$, let $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denote the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. Then
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to0^+}x\left(\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor
> +\left\lfloor\frac{2}{x}\right\rfloor+\dots
> +\left\lfloor\frac{10}{x}\right\rfloor\right)=\_\_\_
> $$

I know , $\lfloor x\rfloor= x $ if $x\in Z$ & 
                            $n$ if $x\notin Z$  and $n \in Z$ and $ n<x<n+1$.

I don't know how to proceed further !!

Comment: The way you defined $\lfloor x \rfloor$ in the title does not agree with your interpretation in the third line.

Comment: **note**: if $x$ is not an integer $\lfloor x\rfloor \ne x-1$ . However, $\lfloor x\rfloor = x$ "wihout the decimal part after the comma". Eg. $\lfloor 2.568\rfloor = 2$

Comment: Hint : Use $x-1\le \lfloor x \rfloor\le x$

Comment: Hint: change the limit to $\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{1}{y}(\lfloor y\rfloor+\lfloor 2y\rfloor+\dots+\lfloor 10y\rfloor)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{x} -1< \lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor<\frac{1}{x}$

multiplying  by x  we get
$\implies$x[$\frac{1}{x} -1]< x\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor<x[\frac{1}{x}]$

this gives $1-x< \lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor<1$
 taking limit x $\to 0^{+}$ by squeez theorem ,we get 
$ lim_{x\to 0^{+}} x\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor=1$

similarly,

$\frac{2}{x} -1< \lfloor \frac{2}{x}\rfloor<\frac{2}{x}$

multiplying  by x  we get
$\implies$x[$\frac{2}{x} -1]< x\lfloor \frac{2}{x}\rfloor<x[\frac{2}{x}]$

this gives $2-x< \lfloor \frac{2}{x}\rfloor<2$

taking limit x $\to 0^{+}$ by squeez theorem ,we get 
$ lim_{x\to 0^{+}} x\lfloor \frac{2}{x}\rfloor=2$

so this give value of complete expression =55.